# Pipeline to store OpenSearch data into Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am new to using OpenSearch & AWS (no prior Elasticsearch experience). I have to basically collect data from an OpenSearch index and store it all in AWS Storage.

I only have access to the index through the OpenSearch Dashboard, but I can contact the admin if I have any requirements.

What is the best/most efficient way to go about doing this? Should it be done entirely on AWS? Looking up online I am getting a lot of info on doing the reverse of this (AWS to OpenSearch), so I feel I am missing something here. Thanks for any help!

I have implemented GET commands for my desired data on OpenSearch Dev Console (OpenSearch Dashboard) and used Python scripts with those GET commands to get the data that I need, locally. Since the data is big, and is streamed daily on OpenSearch I think storing in AWS is a better choice.